# vector reseve then assign can improve performance

Tags: c++, vector

If have to assign char array  to vector ,Is it  good  practice to first reserve vector  size  then  assign array to it?

will this   improve performance?

beacuse Compiler no need allocate several time internaly so it should improve  performance , but  i am  not sure . 
Is  assign already taking  this in consideration before assigning?

doese assign (reserve) allocate size first and then insert/copy?

**NOTE:-with assign i mean assign function in vector (std::vector::assign)**

example:-

```
 void test_func(char* bigarray)
{
     std::vector<char> v_data;
     int len=strlen(bigarray);
     v_data.reserve(len);
     v_data.assign(bigarray,bigarray+len);
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you're using

Comment: thanks .I added code ,now question is  more  clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this question got downvoted as it seems perfectly valid for someone to ask this, rather than going away and inventing some kind of way to benchmark vector which may or may not give erroneous results.

Anyway...  If you've got a decent sized array that you're going to assign to the vector, it will almost certainly be faster to reserve() before assigning.  However, there are several caveats that mean it might not always be the case.  In fact, it will probably be implementation dependent.

Your vector will have a pre-defined size when it is created, so when the assign() is performed, it's going to start copying the array elements into the vector.  When the vector reaches its capacity, it'll do another allocation of (I think 1.5x or maybe 2x allocation strategy) and copy the elements from one vector to another.  However, this allocation ***may*** actually extend the memory (depending on whether the operating system will allow it) and this copy operation may not take place.  You'll not be able to predict this, as is simply not under your control.

If your input array is of a known size, then it would usually be better to reserve() the space you need ahead of time so as to avoid these possible re-allocation/copy operations.  You can however go one stage better than this though.  The vector constructor takes an argument that allows you to specify the size at the time of its instantiation. This would avoid the need to reserve() in the first place.  (Be aware that you need to understand the difference between resize() and reserve(), one only affects capacity, the other creates the vector of the specified size)

You do need to be aware of fact that if you create a vector of a specified size, then the size() of the vector will be of that size, even if you have inserted far fewer elements.  (You'll be using operator[] to access and insert your elements)

The other question you should probably ask yourself is this:  If you've got your data contained within an array, what is the purpose of moving it into a dynamic container and do you really need to?

Comment: regarding  down vote.  
It may be  my fault.Question was not properly framed , reframed it (edited it).

Comment: Can you name one platform where vector can extend its allocation and avoid copying elements when its capacity grows?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Probably.

Maybe.

Test it and see.

Comment: "No." is missing from the list.

Comment: For the question as asked, *reserve* and assign will likely be UB.

Comment: @krzaq: Not if the `assign()` member function is used.

Comment: Ah, good point. I assumed `operator=` on the indexed element.